# Images not showing in WebBrowser control on c# win forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am fetching some data containing formatted HTML with some images in it for e.g:

```
<p><b>Hello User!</b>some other text here....<img src="../images/u_img/user.png" alt="" /></p>
```

from a hosted Web database server into a windows c# form (.net v4.5) to be shown in a 'WebBrowser' control. The texts are rendering fine but the images are not.This is obvious because of the relative path of the image which which when downloaded does not exist . In order to solve the problem i have even created the same directory structure of image folder in my 'bin->Debug' directory still the problem persists. I hope you understand my problem. I have been searching the internet for possible solution that suits my need but no success yet.

Please advise possibly with code as to what should be my approach to solve this kind of problem..Thanks in advance.

I am using the code below to show data in webbrowser control

```
SQLiteDataReader rdr9e;
        string sql5 = "SELECT q_r_desc FROM loc_tblrip_r WHERE id=@id";
        try
        {
            SQLiteConnection con9e = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
            con9e.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd9e = new SQLiteCommand(sql5, con9e);
            cmd9e.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", comboBox1.Text.ToString());

            cmd9e.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            rdr9e = cmd9e.ExecuteReader();
            if (rdr9e.Read())
            {
                var array = (byte[])rdr9e["q_r_desc"];
                this.webBrowser1.DocumentStream = new MemoryStream(array);
            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

The field 'q_r_desc' contains the formatted HTML data in binary format.

Comment: How are you fetching and storing the web page?

Comment: Equalsk please see my code above.I am not fetching or storing any web page, infact its some formatted html data in binary format that's i am rendering through webbrowser control

Comment: Never mind,..i have found a solution to my problem.

Comment: @gomeshmunda, in such cases you should share your solution. Thank you!

Comment: I solved the problem of image path by encoding the image by base64 and stored into the database.